# Nextjs Router push issue in IIS window

Tags: iis, router, next.js13, next-router

i have deployed my next@js13.5 application on IIS window,erverything wokring fine LINK,Image compoent,SSR all wroking fine except router.push next/router. i have used URL rewrite and httpplatfromhandler.
my web.config is below and my server.js templae provide my nextjs

https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/configuring/custom-server

```
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>    https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/configuring/custom-server
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="myapp">
          <match url="/*" />
          <action type="Rewrite" url="server.js" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>

    <iisnode node_env="production" nodeProcessCommandLine="&quot;C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe&quot;" interceptor="&quot;%programfiles%\iisnode\interceptor.js&quot;" />
   <security>
            <requestFiltering>
                <fileExtensions>
                    <add fileExtension=".pdf" allowed="true" />
                    <add fileExtension=".svg" allowed="true" />
                      <add fileExtension=".jpg" allowed="true" />
          <add fileExtension=".jpeg" allowed="true" />
          <add fileExtension=".png" allowed="true" />
          <add fileExtension=".mp3" allowed="true" />
          <add fileExtension=".mp4" allowed="true" />
          <add fileExtension=".*" allowed="true" />
                </fileExtensions>
        <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="104857600" />
            </requestFiltering>
        </security>
  </system.webServer>
    <location path="" overrideMode="Deny">
        <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
    
      <add name="iisnode" path="server.js" verb="*" modules="iisnode" />
    </handlers>
        </system.webServer>
    </location>
</configuration>
```

i want suggestion why my router.push is not working without IIS it is working fine but in IIS Host it is not workng

Comment: The config file you shared indicates IISNode, not HttpPlatformHandler.

Comment: @LexLi sir ,I was saying I also tried http platformhandler but still same, I used iisnode everything working fine except router.push I am using next/routers. Some js are not loading while router.push

Comment: What error did you get?